# IF Anidados PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Buenos Días Gente; solicito de la colaboración de la comunidad debido a que no me explico porque no se esta evaluando el segundo if que esta anidado, no se esta evaluando e ingresa a si la estructura se true o false ejemplo (1=2) y entra?...

```
LOOP
FETCH c_cursor INTO ID_DOCUMENTO_DO, DIAS_VENCPRORRO, CON_PRORROGA, DIAS_VENCIMIENTO;
   EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        IF (CON_PRORROGA > 0) then
            if(DIAS_VENCPRORRO >0)then
               INSERT INTO GEN_ALERTA
                           (DIAS_VENCIMIENTO)
                           VALUES (DIAS_VENCPRORRO);
             end if;
        ELSE
               INSERT INTO GEN_ALERTA
                           (DIAS_VENCIMIENTO)
                           VALUES (DIAS_VENCIMIENTO);
        END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: ¿Probaste agregando algunas líneas con `DBMS_OUTPUT` (por ejemplo, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CON_PRORROGA = ' || CON_PRORROGA);`) para corroborar los datos?

Comment: si, e igual entra cuando el valor es 0, adicional a esto realize la prueba `IF (2=10) then` y tambien entra...!

Comment: Probaste encerrando el bloque If entre Begin End?

Comment: @Ariel Octavio D'Alfeo,  genial muchas gracias, ya funciono, no entiendo porque?, mil y mil gracias :)

Comment: @Ariel Octavio D'Alfeo, mil disculpas, ya solucione el inconveniente nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego la respuesta que en un principio mencione en un comentario de la pregunta. Se debe agregar el bloque Begin End en los if.

```
LOOP
FETCH c_cursor INTO ID_DOCUMENTO_DO, DIAS_VENCPRORRO, CON_PRORROGA, DIAS_VENCIMIENTO;
   EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        IF (CON_PRORROGA > 0) then
            BEGIN
                  IF (DIAS_VENCPRORRO >0)then
                    BEGIN
                          INSERT INTO GEN_ALERTA
                           (DIAS_VENCIMIENTO)
                           VALUES (DIAS_VENCPRORRO);
                     END;
                  END IF;
            END;
        ELSE
            BEGIN
               INSERT INTO GEN_ALERTA
                           (DIAS_VENCIMIENTO)
                           VALUES (DIAS_VENCIMIENTO);
             END;
        END IF;
END LOOP;
```